# Stretching out an multidimensional array

Tags: matlab

Is there any built in MATLAB command that "stretches" out a multidimensional array into a linear array?

e.g [1,2;3,4] should be come [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) command can do this:

```
x = [1 2; 3 4];
y = reshape(x, 1, []);
```

The empty array `[]` indicates that MATLAB should calculate automatically how many elements should go in that direction (i.e., that you won't have to specify the number of elements in your array).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the colon operator:

```
x = [1 2; 3 4];
y = x(:);
```